# Eclipse and Java 8 content assist

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8

I wanted to check Java 8 integration with Eclipse Luna so I downloaded the M7 Luna from eclipse.org.

After configuring the JDK to jdk8u5, I started some tests.

Let's say you have a nice Runnable like

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
};
```

If you select the

```
new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("foo");
  }
}
```

block and press Ctrl-1 (Quick Fix), you get the suggestion to change it to a lambda, resulting in  `Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("foo");`, which is pretty cool.

But a nicer thing whould be to actually help creating lambda expression.
For instance, if you type `Runnable r = |` (with | being the cursor location) and press ctrl+Space (content-assist), I would have expected to find a *"create a lambda expression from this functional interface"* option in the displayed popup. But nothing new is available.

Do you know if this will be implemented in the future ?
I think it might have something to do with the templates (Java/Editor/Templates in preferences) but I actually  never experimented with them.

Comment: You should be asking these questions at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.tools.jdt or in http://bugs.eclipse.org/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing good proposal right after the `=` is rather tricky as *almost everything* could be placed on the right hand side of an assignment.

Even the old way of implementing a function using an anonymous inner class was not proposed right after the equal sign. You had to type the four characters `new␣` before the suggestion came up. And four characters is exactly what you have to type to create a lambda, `()->`, but at this place proposing the creation of a lambda makes no sense anymore as you have already created it.

So proposing a lambda would require lifting its priority compared to other proposals to appear right after the equal sign but it would still have rather limited benefit. You had to press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> unless you use automatic menu popup, then select “create lambda” to just get either the four characters `()->` or something like `name->` inserted whereas the parameter name(s) are likely to be changed after the proposal is inserted.

For an inner class, read method overriding, it makes sense to propose parameters as you have to repeat all parameter types exactly, but for a lambda where you can omit all the bulk the saving is very limited.

So I don’t expect a proposal of lambda creation to ever appear in the list.

Comment: "almost everything could be placed on the right hand side of an assignment" -- uh ... no. That statement is pretty much the excat opposite of reality. The right-hand assignment can ONLY be a very limited set of things --> objects & fields in the current scope, lambda / functional interfaces in the current scope or classpath, known constants and static expressions aaand thats about it. Im guessing lambda will appear at some time in the future - once the content-assist guys figure out a decent set of rules for it (just like they did in auto-formatting)

Comment: @specializt: **every expression** except `void` method calls can appear right to the assignment operator and thanks to anonymous inner classes this includes entire class definitions. So `package` declarations and `import` statements are the only things which can not appear after an assignment operator. So the bottom line is that *almost everything* can appear after an assignment operator. If you want to go nitpicking, choose a topic you have real knowledge about.

Comment: thats cute ... except for that its utter fantasy. Please go ahead and try to assign a float-value to boolean without explicitly ignoring compiler-errors (if that is even possible) / supressing content-assist warnings. Without explicut conversion and error-ignorance it is impossible to assign "almost anything" to variables. But since you're starting a flamewar right now (insults et cetera) im gonna leave you to your pseudo-academic fantasy of what you wish reality to be. Have fun.

Comment: @specializt: The context of my statement about “almost anything” is the context sensitive help of an IDE that has to provide a list of suggestions put in a list on the screen. That’s the topic of the question here. To stay at your example, after a `boolean-type-variable = ` it **is** valid to put a floating point expression because it might be possible that the user wants to add, e.g. a ` < 0 ` right after that expression. How should an IDE know that when you have just type the `=` of the assignment?